# Problems having python installed in Docker container for GUI software

Tags: python-3.x, docker, numpy, debian-jessie

I would like to install [This](http://www.altimetry.info/toolbox/install_yes/) software called Brat on my Ubuntu-based machine except that Brat requires Debian and I didn't manage to install it on Ubuntu. I thought I could go through a Docker container, for that, I wrote the following Dockerfile where I included the necessary libraries for the software

```
FROM debian:8
WORKDIR /home
COPY . /home

RUN apt-get update && apt install -y curl libgdal-dev libspatialindex-dev libxerces-c-dev \
    libxrandr-dev xsdcxx libegl1-mesa libproj-dev libgeos-c1\
    rsync libsm6 libglu1 libqt5x11extras5 

RUN chmod +x brat-4.2.0-x86_64-installer.run
```

I built an image based on the Dockerfile and then I installed the software manually (because it contains yes/no questions) inside a Docker container (created from the built image) using: `./brat-4.2.0-x86_64-installer.run`. I committed the image and launched the software form my localhost terminal using the following command  `docker run -ti --rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix/:/tmp/.X11-unix new_brat_debian /usr/local/bin/brat` where *new_brat_debian* is the name of the committed image. The software was launched successfully and the GUI window appeared except that I had an error asking for the **Numpy** library to be installed so that the software could function properly. I tried installing **Python3** on Debian and followed every way I could find but without success. At this point I don't know how to fix this issue, I thought about doing *docker multi-stage building* with *new_brat_debian* and a Python-built image but I don't know if it's worth the adventure. Does anyone have an idea or a suggestion on how to include Python in the existing Docker image? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with latest debian

```
FROM debian:latest
```

It's installing python 3.4 and numpy gives error that it requires more than 3.7.

Or

Following worked

```
FROM debian:8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade

RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils python3 python3-pip python3-numpy

RUN pip3 -V

RUN pip3 show numpy
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @PrithviSingh ! The thing is Brat is built on Debian:8, wouldn't Debian latest be an issue for the software?

Comment: Thanks @PrithviSingh the first suggestion didn't work because of incompatibilities between the libraries and the latest version of Debian. The second suggestion worked and I have python3 and numpy installed in my docker container, thank you very much!

Comment: When I launch the software I still get this error though: `File "/usr/local/bin/Python/BratAlgorithm-Example_AlgoUsingNumpy.py", line 42, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
Exception caught loading python algorithm in /usr/local/bin/Python/BratAlgorithm-Example_AlgoUsingNumpy.py with class Example_AlgoUsingNumpy: Error loading Python module.` and when I run the file that causes the error independently it runs without problems. What could be the origin of this error in your opinion? Thanks